# How to configure SSH agent to set user for second hop?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent

Is it possible to connect to a web server and then connect to a git server using SSH agent if the second hop needs a different user?

It works if I pass in the user name explicitly.

```
$ ssh web.example.com
# connects

  > ssh -T yellow@git.example.com
  > # connects
```

It does not work if I rely on the SSH config to set user.

```
$ ssh web.example.com
# connects

  > ssh -T git.example.com
  > # permission denied
```

Here is the SSH config on my machine.

```
Host web.example.com
  User blue
  ForwardAgent yes

Host git.example.com
  User yellow
```

In the debug output it says authenticating as `blue` even though the config sets the user to `yellow` for the host.

```
debug1: Authenticating to git.example.com:22 as 'blue'
```

Why does it use the wrong user? I don't want to hard code the user because then it does not work for the whole team to use the same deploy script.

Comment: The agent doesn't forward anything in your ssh configuration file.  It only deals with handling keys/certs.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to set all settings explicitly in my `~/.ssh/config` with a short alias for each host. That way I won't need to use any commandline flags and can simply type less  and use `ssh Destination` and be done with.

```
Host web
    Hostname web.example.com
    User blue
    ForwardAgent yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes                                  # Specific to OS X 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.blue

Host git
    Hostname git.example.com
    User yellow 
    ForwardAgent yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes                                  # Specific to OS X
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.yellow
    ProxyJump web
```

`ProxyJump` is a relatively new setting that I find somewhat more intuitive to use then a `ProxyCommand`. Now `ssh git` will do exactly what you need, first create a session using `blue@web.example.com` as a first hop from which you tunnel to your next hop with `yellow@git.example.com`.

You can also use the ProxyJump command directly in from the command line :

```
ssh -J blue@web.example.com yellow@git.example.com
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want the web server to run git commands against the git server and download code. If I use proxy will the web server receive new code? or will it relay commands and client machine receives code? I can connect from client to git server no problem without web server. I want the web server to connect too without storing keys or config.